# Issue with PHP Include

Tags: php, php-include

I have a function called uploadfile:

```
<?php
function UploadFile (){
//ftp credentials set here
$connection = ftp_connect($server);
$login = ftp_login($connection, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
if (!$connection || !$login) { die('Connection attempt failed!'); }
$upload = ftp_put($connection, $dest, $source, FTP_ASCII, $startpos = 0);
if (!$upload) { echo 'FTP upload failed!'; }
ftp_close($connection);
}
```

I am calling it like this:

```
<?php
if( isset( $_REQUEST['modify'] ))
{
UploadFile();}
?>
```

The problem is that the code runs as soon as the page loads (without any call to the function). it seems to make no difference where the include_once 'upload file.php' is placed.
Obviously I don't want the code to run until the function is called.
Advice/pointers appreciated...

Comment: print_r( $_REQUEST ) and see if you get modify in it.

Comment: You should edit the piece of code into the question instead of posting it as a comment

Comment: The code is in my original post (when I try to ed=it) but it is not showing...

Comment: Did you try what @BasheerAhmed told you to?

Comment: print_r( $_REQUEST) produced: Array ( [modify] => Modify )

Answer (score 1):

I believe the comments have pretty much answered the question.

The 'include_once' is not going to run the function, it just includes the reference to the function.  You could even put the function in the same file as the if condition and it still won't run unless the if condition is met.

For a case where the function doesn't run, you could change the if condition to:

```
<?php
if(false){
    UploadFile()
}
?>
```

If it is still running every time after this point, you have another call to UploadFile somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Kyle - many thanks for responding. I don't have another reference to UploadFile (just double-checked!). The trigger is the 'if( isset( $_REQUEST['ok'] ))' since if I comment out the action (the call to UploadFile) then it does not run on load. Any further thoughts?? cheers

Comment: This overall question seems to be related to the request variables on page load for the if condition. To keep it from running every time, you'll need a condition that is true only on the times you want to run it.